# Uri.IsWellFormedUriString vs. Regular Expression for Validating a URL

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url

Which is the better way to validate a URL in C#? using `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` or self created regular expression which is robust but can sometimes miss the patterns?

Comment: Use a `[Url]` attribute applied to your property so that you get client and server side validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` is the complete method to do that task - use it.

If you need more, like some refined matching, then attach an `&& MyPattern(uri)` afterwards.

It is a general rule to use built-in solutions to problems, because people who have implemented that method have known at least as much about the problem domain as you do, and usually more, being specialists. Therefore, it is highly unlikely that they have missed some case that you might cover better.